# Check WM_LBUTTONDOWN in a Thread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i have a WindowProcess, which creates a Thread, when the left mouse button is down:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
      InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
      _beginthread(mouseMoveThread, 0, &params);
      return 0;
}
```

And the thread mouseMoveThread sets the Pixel, during the left button is down:

```
void mouseMoveThread(PVOID pvoid)
{
  HDC hdc; 
  PPARAMS pparams = (PPARAMS) pvoid;
  static POINT pt[MAXPOINTS];
  static int iCount;

  while(WM_LBUTTONDOWN){
    if(GetCursorPos(&pt[iCount]))
    {
        if (ScreenToClient(pparams->hwnd, &pt[iCount]))
        {
            iCount++;
            hdc = GetDC(pparams->hwnd);
            SetPixel(hdc, pt[iCount-1].x, pt[iCount-1].y,(COLORREF)RGB(0,255,0));
            ReleaseDC(pparams->hwnd, hdc);
        }
    }
}
_endthread();
}
```

But how can i check in the while-loop, that the left button is down ???

Comment: Why you want while loop for wm_lbuttondown? Why call GetCursorPos, if wm_lbuttondown gave you coords?

Comment: How can I get the coords through WM_LBUTTONDOWN?!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you mean the lParam?

Comment: But i don't have this Parameter in the Thread function

Comment: Yes your GUI thread gets it. Your GUI thread gets all the required information. This is why you must forward it to your thread, as I have said below.

Comment: Tenfour is right. Why you want make complicated thing from simple thing?

Comment: The design of your program is wrong. Your next step is to throw all this away and do it properly. Put your GUI code into the main thread where it belongs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your GUI thread should forward the appropriate messages to the rendering thread. Maybe for your case that's `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`. You could communicate that with `Event` objects for example.

If your "rendering thread" has its own message loop, `AttachThreadInput` might be of interest.

**But this seems pointless. Just do it in the main thread**; there is no reason to create a separate thread here for something that is best done in the GUI thread anyway. You are trying to handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events to follow the mouse cursor. This requires just handling events in the GUI thread. The way you are doing it, you will do exactly the same thing, except from a different thread. **You have introduced a lot of convolution for absolutely no gain**.

A couple other comments about your code:

- You're calling `InvalidateRect` which will induce a `WM_PAINT`. `SetPixel` is a "rogue" call -- the system does not keep track of this, and if you paint in `WM_PAINT`, then your `SetPixel` calls will always be overwritten.  For this reason most apps *only* do painting in `WM_PAINT`.
- If you're not painting in `WM_PAINT`, your `SetPixel` calls will still be forgotten if your window is hidden-and-reshown. The normal solution to all of this painting business is to keep a "back buffer" where you draw to some private bitmap, then on `WM_PAINT` you just copy from it to the window.
- Your thread's loop doesn't make sense, but even if you could `while(WM_LBUTTONDOWN)`, it would be a tight loop. If your mouse remained still, your loop would continue calling `SetPixel` at the same location over and over again at 100% CPU.
- Your thread uses `static` local variables. This means all threads will use the same variables. You have several sync issues here. For example if `iCount` changes between calls to `GetCursorPos` and `ScreenToClient`.
- You never test if `iCount` goes out of bounds.
- What if the user closes your app while the left button is still pressed? You need more exit conditions, driven by the parent thread.

Comment: Maybe with a MessageQueue between WindowProcess and the Thread? And the WindowProcess sends a Message when WM_LBUTTONDOWN is the case?

Comment: No, you should just do this in the main thread by handling these 3 messages.

Comment: If you failed to do it in the GUI thread, your solution is not to pick a more complicated, worse way of doing it. "Mouse dragging" is a state of the GUI thread, not some parallel operation.

Comment: lol, i'm not failed to do it in the GUIThread... i have done this already, and now i want to do it with a thread...

Comment: It's your choice how you want to design your app. I am just trying to give some clarity on the big picture and that there is an objectively better design. Take it or leave it.